# The "delete" feature isn't working on my account on IE and Firefox browsers

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, firefox, internet-explorer

The [How do I delete my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) faq points out that this link:

> [image: delete link]

is available to folk who haven't asked a question and who have at most one contribution.

As you can see, I have the link, and when I click it, I get a helpful confirmation dialog:

> [image: Delete your account?]

but when I click OK it disappears but nothing else in the world appears to change. (Still logged in, name doesn't change to user300032453 etc. Profile still linked to from answer etc.)

- It worked a few days ago and now doesn't work.
- Tested on: IE10 at work and Firefox 25.0.1 at home.
- **Tested on Chrome  31.0.1650.57 m at home: works.** What setting or feature is interfering with this?

(Not sure if it's related, but the popups I was expecting from hovering near the top also seem broken.)

Comment: How many times are you deleting your account? (E.g. why did you do this a few days ago, and are trying again today?)

Comment: Maybe you have deleted question/answer making it more than one posts in total?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think you're going off the topic of the question. The feature isn't working, hence it's a bug. If you like, open up a different question something along the lines of "Why do some people delete their accounts as soon as they make them?" but that's not this question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - But then the bug would be the "delete" link being shown inappropriately and acting confusingly when clicked.

Comment: That's why it was a comment and not an answer. It's still a relevant question IMHO.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope - when that soft of thing happens, the link disappears (as stated in the faq - I can vouch for its accuracy). The link's there, just non-functional.

Comment: @AaronBertrand If it worries you that people use this feature, make a feature request to remove it. This is a bug report. I'm trying to keep it as such without a lengthy debate about motivation etc. I'm prepared to have a debate with you, but please, not under this question; that would be out of place here and contrary to the spirit of a pure question and answer website.

Comment: And when you try to delete your account here on Meta? (I'm sure you'll come back if it succeeds :-))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I successfully deleted an account on Meta to test - I was planning to tag with [stackoverflow] but forgot - done. Can't tell you about other non-meta sites, sorry.

Comment: Weird. Can you monitor network traffic when trying to delete on SO, see what is being sent to the server and what is the response?

Comment: @someotherguy doesn't worry me, I was just asking the question in a place where it seemed relevant to ask. You tell your doctor it hurts when you do this, the first thing he's probably going to suggest is to stop doing this.

Comment: @AaronBertrand But if you ask the mechanic if it's possible to fix the hazard warning lights on your car, you'd rather keep the discussion about why you might use the hazard warning lights separate from trying to isolate the problem. "If you avoid pressing the button, the problem of its inertness disappears" could be construed as rather unhelpful.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Arrggghh! I've now participated enough to make this account lose the delete link. Drat. I'm reluctant to litter the world with more me, but will see if I can attempt to delete a new redundant account and monitor the transaction.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd OK, your question was a good one: I've found out that no network traffic gets generated! Firefox's Inspector in Tools>Web Developer mentions `Noscript` which I can't help feeling is related, and the Network monitor shows there's no activity (unless there's some sneaky AJAX way past Firefox's network monitor).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Pop-ups are blocked, but I don't have an adblocking extension unless my firewall or AV have snuck one in past me. Nope - just checked.

Comment: You might have stumbled on a major bug then... maybe nobody can delete accounts using that button anymore. Will try to reproduce myself.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd As per edit; works in Chrome. At home I tend to err on the security end of the settings spectrum, but can't edit them at work from what I consider quite promiscuous. No amount of trusted zoneness helped in ie at work.

Comment: Do you mean clicking the button does work in Chrome but fails in Firefox and IE browsers?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd exactly.

Comment: Cheers, edited the post to better reflect it.